# How to render the data in table fetches from firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, bootstrap-table

I'm using react with firestore fetch data from firebase and display the data using Bootstrap Table but problem is that data is already pushed into the list but if I'm trying to displaying through the bootstrap table it will not render. I already console.log() on my data it will print in but not display.

Anyone any idea what the problem is this?

Output image

[image]

Here it is my code as well as the browser there is table is printed and console.log() the data is fetched from firebase and store in a list. and I am trying to look into the list but it works data is in the list

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase/fireConfig";
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import paginationFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator";
import * as ReactBootstrap from "react-bootstrap";

function Table() {
  const [speedData, setSpeedData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("vehicle")
      .doc("speed_sensor")
      .collection("speed")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const speed_value = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          speed_value.push(data);
          console.log(`SpeedData :=>> ${data.speed}`);
        });
        setSpeedData({ speedData: speed_value });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  console.log(speedData);
  const colums = [
    { dataField: "timestamp", text: "Timestamp" },
    { dataField: "speed", text: "Speed" },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <BootstrapTable
        keyField="timestamp"
        data={speedData}
        columns={colums}
        pagination={paginationFactory()}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: Could you include the code in the question and not an image of it?

Comment: Also you set ```speedData``` to be an object of arrays then you try to set the data in the BootstrapTable to be the entire object of arrays. What data do you want to pass to the ```data``` parameter specifically?

Comment: Please read up on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is difficult to help with an image of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the above code and it works perfectly.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase/fireConfig";
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import paginationFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator";
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit";
import * as ReactBootstrap from "react-bootstrap";
import charts from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts";
import ReactFusioncharts from "react-fusioncharts";
import Widgets from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.widgets";
import FusionTheme from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion";
import ReactFC from "react-fusioncharts";
import FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
import "./SpeedLog.css";

function SpeedLog() {
  // define chart props
  ReactFC.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Widgets, FusionTheme);

  // Resolves charts dependancy
  charts(FusionCharts);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [speedData, setSpeedData] = useState([]);

  let lastItem;
  let lastSpeed = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("data")
      .doc("MP10ME7969")
      .collection("speed")
      .orderBy("id", "asc")
      .onSnapshot((docs) => {
        const speed_value = [];
        docs.forEach((doc) => {
          speed_value.push(doc.data());
        });
        setSpeedData(speed_value);
        setLoading(true);
      });
  }, []);

  lastItem = speedData[speedData.length - 1];
  if (lastItem !== undefined) {
    const obj = Object.entries(lastItem);
    obj.forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (key === "speed") {
        lastSpeed = value;
      }
    });
  }

  lastItem = speedData[speedData.length - 1];
  if (lastItem !== undefined) {
    const obj = Object.entries(lastItem);
    obj.forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (key === "speed") {
        lastSpeed = value;
      }
    });
  }

  // config widget
  const dataSource = {
    chart: {
      captionpadding: "0",
      origw: "320",
      origh: "300",
      gaugeouterradius: "115",
      gaugestartangle: "270",
      gaugeendangle: "-25",
      showvalue: "1",
      valuefontsize: "30",
      majortmnumber: "13",
      majortmthickness: "2",
      majortmheight: "13",
      minortmheight: "7",
      minortmthickness: "1",
      minortmnumber: "1",
      showgaugeborder: "0",
      theme: "fusion",
    },
    colorrange: {
      color: [
        {
          minvalue: "0",
          maxvalue: "85",
          code: "#999999",
        },
        {
          minvalue: "85",
          maxvalue: "180",
          code: "#F6F6F6",
        },
      ],
    },
    dials: {
      dial: [
        {
          value: lastSpeed,
          bgcolor: "#F20F2F",
          basewidth: "8",
        },
      ],
    },
    annotations: {
      groups: [
        {
          items: [
            {
              type: "text",
              id: "text",
              text: "kmph",
              x: "$gaugeCenterX",
              y: "$gaugeCenterY + 40",
              fontsize: "20",
              color: "#555555",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      text: "SPEED",
      dataField: "speed",
    },
    {
      text: "TIMESTAMP",
      dataField: "timestamp",
    },
  ];

  const defaultSorted = [
    {
      dataField: "id",
      order: "asc",
    },
  ];

  

  return (
    <div className="speedlog">
      <div className="speedlog_widget">
        <ReactFusioncharts
          type="angulargauge"
          width="50%"
          height="50%"
          dataFormat="JSON"
          dataSource={dataSource}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="speedlog_table">
        {loading ? (
          <ToolkitProvider
            bootstrap4
            keyField="id"
            data={speedData}
            columns={columns}
            search
          >
            {(props) => (
              <div>
                <hr />
                <BootstrapTable
                  defaultSorted={defaultSorted}
                  pagination={paginationFactory()}
                  {...props.baseProps}
                />
              </div>
            )}
          </ToolkitProvider>
        ) : (
          <ReactBootstrap.Spinner animation="border" />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SpeedLog;
```

Answer (score 0):

In react hooks, which you are using here, you just need to call the state method, which is `setSpeedData` here and pass in value which is `speed_value` here and it'll automatically set the state `speedData` because the `setSpeedData` method is already assigned to set the state for 'speedData'

So, try `setSpeedData(speed_value)` instead of `setSpeedData({ speedData: speed_value })`

Comment: Ok I follow your step but it will give an error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`